Misplaced omit error using align in table
I get a "misplaced \omit" error message when I use align* in a tabular environment.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Citron}{HTML}{DFCC74}

\newcommand{\bandtable}[3][Citron]{
        \begin{center}
            % \begin{table}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
                \hline
                \rowcolor{#1}
                \vspace{0.7mm}
                #2
                \vspace{2mm}\\ \vspace{1mm} %Title for box
                #3                                 %Content
                \vspace{2mm}
                \\\hline
            \end{tabular}
            % \end{table}
        \end{center}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\bandtable[Citron]{Header}{Some text

{\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
}
}

\end{document}

The error message is:
! Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit 
                                                  \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...

I looked at the answers to an earlier "misplaced \omit" posting but they didn't work. The error does go away if I use split, as employed here.
Can anyone suggest how to use align*?

why are you using tabular with a single column? does your real table have more columns and that's just a simplification?

If no equation number is needed, aligned is a much better choice.

@cfr I'd presumed that I'd need a tabular environment for the two rows of my table. The first one being the band.

I suggest you replace
{\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
}

with either
\begin{center}
$\begin{aligned}
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{aligned}$
\end{center}

or
\[
  \begin{aligned}
  2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
  3x + 9y &=  -12
  \end{aligned}
\]

The first method requires a marginally larger typing effort -- \begin{center}$ and $\end{center} instead of \[ and \] -- but will also result in the material being typeset (slightly) more compactly.

That said, I think you would be better off using the tcolorbox machinery to typeset this material. It'll give you far more sophisticated, yet still robust, ways to control the layout and overall appearance of the material at hand.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' and 'align*' environments
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Citron}{HTML}{DFCC74}

\newcommand{\bandtable}[3][Citron]{%
    \begin{center}
        % \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{#1}  % background color of header row
        \vspace{0.7mm}
        #2             % Title for box
        \vspace{2mm}\\ 
        \vspace{1mm} 
        #3             % Content
        \vspace{2mm}
        \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        % \end{table}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\bandtable{Header}{Some text % 'Citron' is default value for #1
  \begin{center}
    $\begin{aligned}
    2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
    3x + 9y &=  -12
    \end{aligned}$
  \end{center}
}

\end{document}


I suppose this answer is quite similar -- other than the idea of using a center environment -- to @Bernard's answer to the posting which the OP has referenced. I'm not sure why the OP claims that the aligned approach "doesn't work".

Congratulations! You've discovered that align (and align* as well) cannot be used when colortbl is loaded; adding braces around the environment only cures one problem, but not the main one.
You might define a suitable environment for this or use systeme for the particular case.
However, you may find it better to use tcolorbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{systeme}% have a look at it

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{Citron}{HTML}{DFCC74}

\newcommand{\bandtable}[3][Citron]{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{#1}
    \rule[-4mm]{0pt}{10mm}#2% title
    \\
    \rule{0pt}{4mm}\ignorespaces #3
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}

% for the first solution
\NewDocumentEnvironment{talign}{b}{\[\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}\]}{}

% for the third solution
\newtcolorbox{newbandtable}[2][Citron]{
  left skip=\dimeval{0.05\textwidth-\tabcolsep},
  right skip=\dimeval{0.05\textwidth-\tabcolsep},
  left=\tabcolsep,
  right=\tabcolsep,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=#1,
  coltitle=black,
  title=\rule[-2mm]{0pt}{6mm}#2,
}

\begin{document}

\bandtable[Citron]{Header}{
Some text
\begin{talign} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{talign}
}

\bigskip

\bandtable[Citron]{Header}{
Some text
\[\systeme{
2x - 5y =  8,
3x + 9y =  -12
}\]
}

\bigskip

\begin{newbandtable}{Header}
Some text
\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
\end{newbandtable}

\end{document}


You see that the output of the third box (with tcolorbox) is the same as the others. And you can use align*, if you so prefer.
